# Cómo configurar las zonas horarias con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Cómo es la mejor manera de utilizar las zonas horarias desde base de datos (MySQL) por usuario o aplicación? estoy usando PHP (codeigniter) para el desarrollo.

Existe alguna referencia o publicación del tema?

Gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, lee [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
La zona horaria depende netamente del tipo de aplicación a desarrollar, no hay una forma correcta pero si diferentes métodos para utilizar. Si tus usuarios son de diferentes paises lo mejor es almacenar todo en UTC y luego convertir a las respectivas zonas horarias, si tus usuarios son del mismo pais, puedes usar la zona horaria de tu pais, si la fecha y hora son criticas para tu aplicación, pasa estos datos desde el backend siempre y no los rescates del cliente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @CésarAlejandroM, es la respuesta que necesitaba.

Comment: Haz tu pregunta más especifica y dependiendo de lo que necesites, puedo profundizar en una solución.

Comment: Hola @CésarAlejandroM , gracias por la ayuda. Voy a trabajar con sucursales, en donde en cada sucursal se encuentra en diferentes estados de México, los usuarios del sistema estarán asignados solamente a una sola sucursal. El objetivo del sistema es poder ver el tiempo real sin importar la diferencia de horarios, la disponibilidad y tiempo de entrega de productos que se estarán trabajando. De nuevo gracias por el tiempo, saludos.

Comment: Entonces tu problema no es tanto la hora, si no la persistencia del registro de stock y el acceso a esta información. Te recomiendo leer un poco de websocket o ajax polling.
En mi experiencia, websocket suele ser un poco más complejo de implementar si no tienes conocimiento previo, ajax polling es como el truco feo para conseguir la funcionalidad de websocket, eventualmente trabajar ajax polling y una frecuencia de consultas muy alta puede asesinar tu servidor, sobre todo si este está limitado en cantidad de procesos simultáneos o E/S.

Éxito en el desarrollo!